# Is there any way to manipulate <script> tags using Selenium Web driver for java?

Tags: java, selenium

I am working on an web application which has a query form to give search criteria. Once the query criteria is filled out in the form and searched, a table loads below the search form.

Now this table is not formed by usual *tr* and *td* tags but is made up of several script tags like-

```
<TABLE>
<THEAD>...</THEAD>
<TBODY>
<SCRIPT>
    var colElm1 = document.createElement("SPAN");
    colElm1.innerText = "ABCD";
    rowElm1.appendChild(colElm1);
</SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT>
    var colElm1 = document.createElement("SPAN");
    colElm1.innerText = "AB_CD123";
    rowElm1.appendChild(colElm1);
</SCRIPT> 
....
</TBODY>
</TABLE>
```

Now my problem is that is there any way to get the "ABCD" and "AB_CD123" using selenium and not using regex on the whole source code ?

Comment: Are you looking at the HTML of the page loaded in a browser? It looks like you might be looking at the source of the HTML page before it's loaded or on the wrong part of the page. Find the text you want in a browser and inspect it, then you can find the HTML to create locators from.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**
Misunderstood the question, I thought You wanted to change the content of `<script>` tags.

the You can probably do this for all `<script>` tags one by one using `JavascriptExecutor` as below :

```
WebElement scriptTag1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table//tbody/script[1]"));
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
//you can use following line
js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', 'your new value');", scriptTag1);

//or if above line doesn't work then following line
 js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('innerHTML', 'your new value');", scriptTag1);
```

> 'your new value' should provide whole content of `<script...</script>` tag

Answer (score 0):

As the code in Script tag shows it will append SPAN into element 'rowElm1'.

```
rowElm1.appendChild(colElm1);
```

This 'rowElm1' should be some element from page, once you find where assign value to 'rowElm1' from the whole page source,  you will know how to find it from page and then you will see all text of appened SPAN will display inside the 'rowElm1'.

So you no need to obtain the text of SPAN from SCRIPT tag, you should get them from the element 'rowElm1' on page.

```
driver.findElement(locator of 'rowElm1').getText();
```

Comment: The rowElm1 is also present inside a script tag and it is present inside the `<TBODY>` tag as -
`<SCRIPT>`
 `var rowElm1 = document.createElement("SPAN");`
 `col_count = 0;`
`</SCRIPT>`

Comment: please find out the rowElm1  append to where? The key point of the solution is to find out all such appended stuff are insert to which existed element on page.

Comment: Ok,
Now I understood what you meant. Thanks a lot